# Are questions about how to use desktop applications on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343322/dbeaver-export-to-csv-no-database-selected) which is about the correct way to use the desktop SQL client [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/).  My first instinct was to close the question as off topic - especially since it seems the OP simply forgot to add a semicolon between statements.  The OP then clarified that they believe it's a specifically a problem related to DBeaver - which I now agree with since they need to select the DB in the top menu bar of that application for their export to work.

This doesn't really seem like a programming question to me and I don't see how it could be on topic here - however, given that the tag exists and has garnered hundreds of questions, I'm in doubt.

Comment: DBeaver is an IDE, and so questions about it tend to be on topic. It's if the applicable wouldn't be primarily used to programming then questions about it would be off topic; for example how to do something in Microsoft Word (that isn't Marco related).

Comment: Ok, I wouldn't call DBeaver an IDE but I see your point.

Comment: What *would* you call it then? I would certainly say it is; it's an open source database development and administration tool. IDE means "Integrated development environment" and you can most certainly develop in DBeaver.

Comment: I don't know much about the tech, but looking at it briefly, the tool does appear to be one programmers would use, and the linked question on main is asking for help with using it for a programming related task. It looks on-topic to me.

Comment: @Larnu - I would call it a SQL client. There is a DBeaver plugin for the the IDE Eclipse.

Comment: By your definition then, @billynoah , SSMS isn't a IDE; I can assure you it is. It seems, if I am honest, that the problem was your understanding of what DBeaver is was the problem as it's an IDE; and again questions about IDE are on topic.

Comment: The [Help Center says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *"...software tools commonly used by programmers..."*

Comment: @Peter: "AND is unique to software development".  Database access from a GUI is not software development.  Database access is not unique to software development.

Comment: @Larnu: SSMS isn't primarily an IDE, it's a management tool.  Use of the integrated debugger is definitely on-topic, since that is a developer (sub)tool.  Use of the data entry or backup/restore functions are off-topic.

Comment: It's been deprecated, @BenVoigt . It's still an IDE...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are questions about how to use desktop applications on topic here?

YES, ***IF*** that desktop application is one whose *primary function* is related to the development of—or using—a programming language found on Stack Overflow.

Examples of numerous, accepted Stack Overflow questions on non-language desktop applications include PhpStorm, Docker, MySQL Workbench, Unity3D, etc.

The regularity and volume of questions I have seen regarding these IDEs does strongly imply that IDEs themselves are not an issue when they are relevant to programming via these applications.

Comment: thanks I think this threw me because it looked like a SQL question but then turned out to be a usage problem.  Your answer makes sense.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I would be cautious about using the existence of questions as a justification for, or against, a particular question being allowed (if that's the intent of the statement). There are, unfortunately, quite a lot of off-topic questions that are still open on the site, and that's often used as a reason for not closing some specific off-topic question.

Comment: Questions about SQL *are* on topic for [so] though, @billynoah , so what do you mean that the question was about SQL threw you?

Comment: @cigien yes I debated with myself weather to add examples I'm aware of but decided that due to quantity they could be included, the volume of questions I have seen regularly on these IDEs does strongly imply that IDEs themselves are not an issue.

Comment: @Larnu - I mean *if it was about sql* it was off topic because it's bascially a typo (missing semi colon).  As it turns out, the problem has nothing to do with the semi-colon but is in fact about how to use DBeaver.

Comment: You are correct, but you can't state it as broadly as "questions about IDE's are on-topic" - the "must be a programming problem" bit still has to apply. If an IDE interface shows graphical corruption... that's bad luck, but it's not a programming problem. Probably a driver issue or a bug in the software itself. If you don't know how to install/setup your favorite font... tough luck, I'm sure the IDE has a manual. Questions about IDE usage for the act of programming are the juicy bits we want to hoard.

Comment: @Gimby - based on your point of view, do you personally feel the question mentioned in my question is on topic?  it seems to be more related to a quirky UI and I'm still honestly not sure where that falls.

Comment: @Gimby: No, all technical questions (so excluding purchasing and licensing and vendor support contracts) about tools whose exclusive purpose is software development are on-topic.  Including graphical corruption in an IDE.  But a tool for database access does not have the exclusive or even primary purpose of software development, such tools also support network administration and data entry tasks, such as making and restoring backups, interactive queries, diagramming database structure, and so on.